# How to align `tcolorbox` at the top?

Tags: vertical-alignment, description, tcolorbox

I want to align `Some text` with `Lead Programmer` like this:

[image]

But the `leftrulebox` (a `tcolorbox`) inside the description environment doesn't align properly. The following code gives this:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=60pt,top=60pt,right=60pt,bottom=60pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setitemize{nolistsep,labelsep=1ex,leftmargin=*}
%% colors---
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.8}
%%items--
\newlist{items}{description}{1}
\setlist[items]{align=right,font=\normalfont, leftmargin=1.8in,style=nextline,labelsep=1em,}
%% leftrulebox---
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}
\newtcolorbox{leftrulebox}{
    colback=white,
    left=0.5ex,
    top=0pt,
    arc=0pt,
    outer arc=0pt,
    leftrule=1pt,
    rightrule=0pt,
    toprule=0pt,
    bottomrule=0pt,
    breakable,
    enhanced jigsaw
    }
%
%

\begin{document}
\begin{items}
\item[Some text]%
\begin{leftrulebox}
\par
\textbf{Lead Programmer}, Social Networks Inc \par
Some text \par some text
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Reengineered multiple systems that fueled improvements to productivity, eficiency, uptime and accuracy for global business operations. Developed code, system design and test/QA plans for all solutions and often coordinated the national or international rollout.
    \item Led, architected and participated in the design, testing and deployment of client/server, multi-tier applications, ActiveX and related components.
    \item Developed new procedures for requirements gathering, needs analysis, testing, scripting and documentation to strengthen quality and functionality of business-critical applications.
\end{itemize}

\kant[1-5]
\end{leftrulebox}
\end{items}
\end{document}
```

## Question

1. What causes this downward shift of `Some text`?
2. How to align `Some text` with `Lead Programmer...`

**Caveat**

1. I can't use any form of `tabular` (including `longtable`) as I need the rule to continue at a page break. `longtable` too won't break across pages inside a row.

---

## Edit:

As noted by Gonzalo, using `\leavevmode` and some negative `vskip` works for same kind of contents in the box. But for the code below, I had to give different `vskip`s for different boxes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=60pt,top=60pt,right=60pt,bottom=60pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setitemize{nolistsep,labelsep=1ex,leftmargin=*}
%% colors---
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.8}
%%items--
\newlist{items}{description}{1}
\setlist[items]{align=right,font=\normalfont, leftmargin=1.8in,style=nextline,labelsep=1em,}
%% leftrulebox---
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}
\newtcolorbox{leftrulebox}{
    colback=white,
    left=0.5ex,
    top=0pt,
    arc=0pt,
    outer arc=0pt,
    leftrule=1pt,
    rightrule=0pt,
    toprule=0pt,
    bottomrule=0pt,
    breakable,
    nobeforeafter,
    enhanced jigsaw,
    before=\vskip-16.5pt       %% I want to define this here globally
    }
%
%

\begin{document}
\section*{Objective}
\begin{items}
\item[Objective]%
\leavevmode
\begin{leftrulebox}
\kant[1]
\end{leftrulebox}
\end{items}

\section*{Positions}
\begin{items}
\item[\raggedleft 1/2010 -- 2/2012]%
\leavevmode
\begin{leftrulebox}
\textbf{Lead Programmer}, Social Networks Inc \par
Some text \par some text\par
  \begin{itemize}%[labelsep=1ex]
    \item Reengineered multiple systems that fueled improvements to productivity, eficiency, uptime and accuracy for global business operations. Developed code, system design and test/QA plans for all solutions and often coordinated the national or international rollout.
    \item Led, architected and participated in the design, testing and deployment of client/server, multi-tier applications, ActiveX and related components.
    \item Developed new procedures for requirements gathering, needs analysis, testing, scripting and documentation to strengthen quality and functionality of business-critical applications.
\end{itemize}
\end{leftrulebox}
\end{items}
\begin{items}
\item[1/2009 -- 2/2010]%
\leavevmode
\begin{leftrulebox}
\textbf{Programmer I}, The Coolest Search Engine \par
  \begin{itemize}%[labelsep=1ex]
    \item Led solutions engineering that involved process automation, macro conversion and functionality enhancement. Replaced time-consuming, error prone manual processes with elegant, automated solutions.
    \item Developed and implemented cross-platform, Java-based POS system. Completed project under budget and three weeks ahead of deadline.
    \item Coded new solutions that increased availability and scalability by 45\% and 75\%, respectively.
\end{itemize}
\end{leftrulebox}
\end{items}

\section*{Skills}
\begin{items}
\item[\textbf{Systems}]%
\leavevmode
\begin{leftrulebox}
\kant[1-2]
\end{leftrulebox}
\end{items}
\begin{items}
\item[\textbf{Others}]%
\leavevmode
\begin{leftrulebox}
some short text here
\end{leftrulebox}
\end{items}
\begin{items}
\item[\textbf{Databases}]%
\leavevmode
\begin{leftrulebox}
some short text here
\end{leftrulebox}
\end{items}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

The alignment of items under **Objective** and **Positions**  are satisfactory while with **Systems**, **Others** and **Databases** it is not. This happens because I have given a *global* `vskip` (which I want to give).

The amount by which the boxes move vertically *depends on the content* (AAArgh) and I can't define a global `vskip`.

Since, unfortunately, this script will be used in an automatic way where, I don't have control over the content, I can't determine the amount of `vskip` for different items. Hence, I can't define it globally.  How to over come this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Updated version

After the edit with the question, I propose a different approach here not using a list to place the labels but reducing the width for the `tcolorbox` and using an optional argument (it could easily be turned into mandatory) and the `overlay` key to place the label at a fixed vertical position; since the label is placed inside a node of fixed width and with `align=right`, they admit line breaking and raggedleft texts (feel free to change the lengths according to your needs):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=60pt,top=60pt,right=60pt,bottom=60pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\setitemize{nolistsep,labelsep=1ex,leftmargin=*}

%% colors---
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.8}

%%items--
\newlist{items}{description}{1}
\setlist[items]{align=right,font=\normalfont, leftmargin=1.8in,style=nextline,labelsep=1em,}

%% leftrulebox---
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}
\newtcolorbox{leftrulebox}[1][]{
    colback=white,
    left=0.5ex,
    top=0pt,
    arc=0pt,
    outer arc=0pt,
    enlarge left by=1.8in,
    enlarge right by=-\dimexpr1.8in+\parindent\relax,
    right=\dimexpr1.8in+\parindent\relax,
    leftrule=1pt,
    rightrule=0pt,
    toprule=0pt,
    bottomrule=0pt,
    breakable,
    nobeforeafter,
    enhanced jigsaw,
    overlay={
      \node[anchor=north east,inner ysep=0pt,align=right,text width=1.5in] 
        at ([yshift=-0.55ex]frame.north west) {\hfill#1};
    },
    before=\vskip2\itemsep\noindent
  }

\begin{document}

\section*{Objective}

\begin{leftrulebox}[Objective]
\kant[1]
\end{leftrulebox}

\section*{Positions}

\begin{leftrulebox}[1/2010 -- 2/2012]
\textbf{Lead Programmer}, Social Networks Inc \par
Some text \par some text
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Reengineered multiple systems that fueled improvements to productivity, eficiency, uptime and accuracy for global business operations. Developed code, system design and test/QA plans for all solutions and often coordinated the national or international rollout.
    \item Led, architected and participated in the design, testing and deployment of client/server, multi-tier applications, ActiveX and related components.
    \item Developed new procedures for requirements gathering, needs analysis, testing, scripting and documentation to strengthen quality and functionality of business-critical applications.
    \end{itemize}
\end{leftrulebox}

\begin{leftrulebox}[1/2009 -- 2/2010]
\textbf{Programmer I}, The Coolest Search Engine
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Led solutions engineering that involved process automation, macro conversion and functionality enhancement. Replaced time-consuming, error prone manual processes with elegant, automated solutions.
    \item Developed and implemented cross-platform, Java-based POS system. Completed project under budget and three weeks ahead of deadline.
    \item Coded new solutions that increased availability and scalability by 45\% and 75\%, respectively.
\end{itemize}
\end{leftrulebox}

\section*{Skills}

\begin{leftrulebox}[\textbf{Systems}]
\kant[1-2]
\end{leftrulebox}

\begin{leftrulebox}[\textbf{Others}]
some short text here
\end{leftrulebox}

\begin{leftrulebox}[\textbf{Databases}]
some short text here
\end{leftrulebox}

\end{document}
```

Some images showing the label alignment:

[image]

[image]

[image]

### First version

After `\item[some text]` TeX is in vertical mode and this produces the undesired effect. Add `\leavevmode`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=60pt,top=60pt,right=60pt,bottom=60pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setitemize{nolistsep,labelsep=1ex,leftmargin=*}
%% colors---
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.8}
%%items--
\newlist{items}{description}{1}
\setlist[items]{align=right,font=\normalfont, leftmargin=1.8in,style=nextline,labelsep=1em,}
%% leftrulebox---
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}
\newtcolorbox{leftrulebox}{
    colback=white,
    left=0.5ex,
    top=0pt,
    arc=0pt,
    outer arc=0pt,
    leftrule=1pt,
    rightrule=0pt,
    toprule=0pt,
    bottomrule=0pt,
    breakable,
    enhanced jigsaw,
    before=\vskip-13.5pt
    }
%
%

\begin{document}
\begin{items}
\item[Some text]%
\leavevmode
\begin{leftrulebox}
\par
\textbf{Lead Programmer}, Social Networks Inc \par
Some text \par some text
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Reengineered multiple systems that fueled improvements to productivity, eficiency, uptime and accuracy for global business operations. Developed code, system design and test/QA plans for all solutions and often coordinated the national or international rollout.
    \item Led, architected and participated in the design, testing and deployment of client/server, multi-tier applications, ActiveX and related components.
    \item Developed new procedures for requirements gathering, needs analysis, testing, scripting and documentation to strengthen quality and functionality of business-critical applications.
\end{itemize}

\kant[1-5]
\end{leftrulebox}
\end{items}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Using just `\leavevmode` the box will be slightly down, due to the regular spacing before a `tcolorbox`; you can correct this by using a convenient `\vskip` for `before` either globally (as in my example) or locally, by adding an optional argument to pass options to the `tcolorbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=60pt,top=60pt,right=60pt,bottom=60pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setitemize{nolistsep,labelsep=1ex,leftmargin=*}
%% colors---
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.8}
%%items--
\newlist{items}{description}{1}
\setlist[items]{align=right,font=\normalfont, leftmargin=1.8in,style=nextline,labelsep=1em,}
%% leftrulebox---
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}
\newtcolorbox{leftrulebox}[1][]{
    colback=white,
    left=0.5ex,
    top=0pt,
    arc=0pt,
    outer arc=0pt,
    leftrule=1pt,
    rightrule=0pt,
    toprule=0pt,
    bottomrule=0pt,
    breakable,
    enhanced jigsaw,
    #1
    }
%
%

\begin{document}
\begin{items}
\item[Some text]
\leavevmode
\begin{leftrulebox}[before=\vskip-13.5pt]
\par
\textbf{Lead Programmer}, Social Networks Inc \par
Some text \par some text
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Reengineered multiple systems that fueled improvements to productivity, eficiency, uptime and accuracy for global business operations. Developed code, system design and test/QA plans for all solutions and often coordinated the national or international rollout.
    \item Led, architected and participated in the design, testing and deployment of client/server, multi-tier applications, ActiveX and related components.
    \item Developed new procedures for requirements gathering, needs analysis, testing, scripting and documentation to strengthen quality and functionality of business-critical applications.
\end{itemize}

\kant[1-5]
\end{leftrulebox}
\end{items}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @HarishKumar I did some tests with different amounts of text and everything worked OK with the same length for the `\vskip`. I'll be looking forward to seeing your edit.

Comment: @HarishKumar You're right. My test examples were deceiving. Now a new idea has formed in my head. Would you be willing to use a different approach? (not using a list at all, but keeping the `tcolorbox`es).

Comment: Sure; it will break across pages. Will the `leftrulebox` always start at the same constant distance from the left margin? If this is so, my idea could work; otherwise, I can discard it :)

Comment: @HarishKumar You're welcome! Thanks for the bounty :) Have a nice weekend you too!

Answer (score 6):

I want suggest another possibility. It still needs some work but let me know if it's interesting.

`\tcolorboxes` have `upper` and `lower` parts which can be placed side by side. Therefore instead of trying to align some external text with a `tcolorbox` text, place both inside. External text will be `upper text` and interior one will be `lower text` and `left hand` rule will be `segmentation rule` inside `tcolorbox`.

I couldn't find how to customize segmentation line but I've solved using `overlays`.

They main problem still to solve is how to automatically decide `lefthand width` to fix enough space for left hand column. I've tried with `\widthof` but didn't worked.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=60pt,top=60pt,right=60pt,bottom=60pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{calc}
\setitemize{nolistsep,labelsep=1ex,leftmargin=*}
%% colors---
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.8}
%%items--
\newlist{items}{description}{1}
\setlist[items]{align=right,font=\normalfont, leftmargin=1.8in,style=nextline,labelsep=1em,}
%% leftrulebox---
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}
\newtcolorbox{leftrulebox}{
    colback=white,
    left=0.5ex,
    top=0pt,
    arc=0pt,
    outer arc=0pt,
    leftrule=0pt,
    rightrule=0pt,
    toprule=0pt,
    bottomrule=0pt,
    breakable,
    enhanced jigsaw,
    sidebyside,sidebyside align=top,
    lefthand width=2cm,
    segmentation hidden,
    overlay={\draw[red] (segmentation.north)--(segmentation.south);}
    }

\begin{document}
\begin{leftrulebox}
Some text
\tcblower
\textbf{Lead Programmer}, Social Networks Inc \par
Some text \par some text
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Reengineered multiple systems that fueled improvements to productivity, eficiency, uptime and accuracy for global business operations. Developed code, system design and test/QA plans for all solutions and often coordinated the national or international rollout.
    \item Led, architected and participated in the design, testing and deployment of client/server, multi-tier applications, ActiveX and related components.
    \item Developed new procedures for requirements gathering, needs analysis, testing, scripting and documentation to strengthen quality and functionality of business-critical applications.
\end{itemize}

\kant[1]
\end{leftrulebox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice idea but unfortunately, I had already tried it. As I wanted page breaks, and this won't break across pages, I gave up (`sidebyside` won't break). Sorry. But don't delete your answer, it may be useful to somebody. Thanks for trying out. Have a nice day and weekend. :)

Comment: @HarishKumar: You're right, I've forgotten it. I cannot test it now but do you think that using a `tcbox` (size adjusted to content) for left hand text and a breakable `tcolorbox` (with calculated width) for right hand text has any sense? This way both top lines would be aligned.

Comment: Ignasi:  Any new idea (however odd it may sound) is welcome. If you want to try anything like that please go ahead. If I like that and if it works, I will give you a bounty for sure. :)