# List environment (itemize) with vertical line between label and content

Tags: lists

Is it possible to have list environments (itemize, enumerate, ...) which have a vertical line between the label (i.e. the bullet/number) and the listing content?

Probably this is best explained using an image, I want to achieve something like this:

[image: List]

**Edit:** Some more info on the intended behaviour: If a pagebreak occurs, the line should naturally continue on the new page.

Comment: If you don't mind to use several `tcolorbox` instead of one `itemize`, take a look at [Gonzalo's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/170767/1952) in [How to align `tcolorbox` at the top?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170757/how-to-align-tcolorbox-at-the-top). You'll have to change box dimensions and use `$\bullet$` as optional parameter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `tcolorbox` version which allows page breaks and is heavily customizable:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\newtcolorbox{mybox}{
  freelance,
  breakable,
  colback=white,
  top=0pt,
  frame code={                          %%decoration code for unbreakable version
    \draw(frame.north west)--(frame.south west);
    \node[at=(frame.north west),anchor=north east,xshift=-5pt,circle,fill=black, inner sep=3pt]{};
  },
  extend freelancefirst={               %%decoration code for breakable version, first page
    frame code={
      \draw(frame.north west)--(frame.south west);
      \node[at=(frame.north west),anchor=north east,xshift=-5pt,circle,fill=black]{};
    },
  },
  extend freelancemiddle={              %%decoration code for breakable version, middle pages
    frame code={
      \draw(frame.north west)--(frame.south west);
    },
  },
  extend freelancelast={                %%decoration code for breakable version, last page
    frame code={
      \draw(frame.north west)--(frame.south west);
    },
  },
}

\newcommand{\myitem}[1]{\item\begin{mybox}#1\end{mybox}}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
  \myitem{one line}
  \myitem{two

  lines}
  \myitem{\lipsum}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

A solution with `mdframed`, that also allows page breaks in the item. Not that I endorse this layout.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,mdframed}

\mdfdefinestyle{litem}{
  skipabove=0pt,
  skipbelow=0pt,
  leftmargin=\dimexpr\leftmargini-\fboxrule-2pt\relax,
  rightmargin=0pt,
  innerleftmargin=2pt,
  innerrightmargin=0pt,
  innertopmargin=0pt,
  innerbottommargin=0pt,
  leftline=true,
  rightline=false,
  topline=false,
  bottomline=false,
}

\newenvironment{litemize}{\trivlist\item\relax}{\endtrivlist}
\newenvironment{litem}
  {%
   \par\addvspace{3\itemsep}
   \begin{mdframed}[style=litem]
   \makebox[0pt][r]{\textbullet\hspace{\dimexpr\labelsep+2pt+\fboxrule}}\ignorespaces
  }
  {%
   \end{mdframed}
  }

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{itemize}
\item a
\item b
\end{itemize}
Some text to separate the two environments
\begin{litemize}
  \begin{litem}
  \lipsum*[2]
  \end{litem}

  \begin{litem}
  \lipsum*[3]
  \end{litem}

  \begin{litem}
  A fairly small one!
  \end{litem}
\end{litemize}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here is my *not so elegant and very lame* solution: using `tabular` within the itemize.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand{\LinedItem}[1]{\item \begin{tabular}[t]{|p{10cm}}#1\end{tabular}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{itemize} 
    \LinedItem{\lipsum[2]}
    \LinedItem{\lipsum[3]}
    \LinedItem{A fairly small one!}
\end{itemize}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Few possible updates that I leave to you to test are: Instead of `p{10cm}`, try something more general like `p{\SomeInterestingWidth}`. Secondly, you can try with other packages such as `tabularx` to change the behavior in the line break.

Comment: `\begin{tabular}[t]` would be more intuitive.

Comment: @egreg, indeed you are right. I did as you suggested. Thanks.

Comment: how does one extend this to include `\item[label]`?

Comment: @DebanjanBasu, as easy as `\newcommand{\LinedItem}[1]{\item[label] \begin{tabular}[t]{|p{10cm}}#1\end{tabular}}`

Comment: no no. I mean I want to use `\LinedItem[label] text ... `-  the label will not be the same all the times and hence wouldn't be mentioned in the macro definition.