# Suggested objects permitting table-like-column formatting and page breaks amidst long lists of breakable content

Tags: tables, formatting, page-breaking

My preferred way of structuring and formatting large lists of content is with `longtable`. Some of my cells contain a lot of text, both in paragraph and itemize or enumerate environments. For reasons explained to me very clearly by David Carlisle page breaks are only possible when rows end/begin, so I end up with enormous portions of blank space.  I haven't yet forced a situation to see how my compile would fail if the box itself couldn't be contained on 1 full page. Since my content is not unbreakable like an image, I'd like to know what other latex environments I could be using that would let me preserve formatting (vertical and horizontal lines, column widths etc.) but break across multiple pages?  Is there a text only environment that I could be using (text only might mean that breaks are expected - no pictures)?

I have seen years worth of repeated questions asking how to do this, but I haven't found a workable answer in any of them.  So I am hopeful that a solution has evolved at some point, it's just been hard to find.

I can't provide a MWE for every other environments that don't seem to work (a sampling of those I remember trying to use is listed below) and I haven't provided a MWE for longtable since I know it can't be modified to permit a page break mid-row.

- minipage
- parbox
- colorbox
- tabular
- mdframed
- and many others

`longtable` was selected for me because:

- it could be combined with `threeparttable`
- it could span multiple pages
- cells could contain long content blocks
- supported `multicolumn` and `multirow`
- column formatting commands were easily customized
- excellent support from knowledgeable users
- good documentation

Answer (score 1):

So far, I have been succeeding working around these complex alignment possibilities and strict requirements by combining

- `tcolorbox`
- `minipage`
- `longtable` + https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/279047/69378
- `threeparttable`

This answer (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/170767/69378) got me going in getting a base formatting and easily adjustable size structure in place.  Then when I coupled it with the table packages described above I was off and running again.  Still working and tweaking the appearances and nested objects, but overall this combination has been working pretty well with the strange alignments and breakable requirements I need.

I didn't make it far enough into the documentation or examples but `flowfram` is also high on my priority for learning as I think it has great promise in some more sticky applications in the foreseeable future.