# tcolorbox disable repeated text in overlayed node

Tags: page-breaking, nodes, tcolorbox

In the following MWE (built from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/170767/69378) I have demonstrated that title text in an overlayed `tcolorbox` node gets repeated across page breaks.

I have checked the manual against each of the arguments being configured, and tried commenting out ones I thought might be the culprit, but I am always left with this repeated title.  Normally this is a fine feature, but I want to be able to selectively turn this off, when the `tcolorbox` is small and repeating this title just increases clutter.

What is forcing this repeat?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=60pt,top=60pt,right=60pt,bottom=60pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\setitemize{nolistsep,labelsep=1ex,leftmargin=*}

%% colors---
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.8}

%%items--
\newlist{items}{description}{1}
\setlist[items]{align=right,font=\normalfont, leftmargin=1.8in,style=nextline,labelsep=1em,}

%% leftrulebox---
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}
\newtcolorbox{leftrulebox}[1][]{
    colback=white,
    boxrule=10pt
    left=0.5ex,
    top=0pt,
    arc=0pt,
    outer arc=0pt,
    enlarge left by=1.8cm,
    enlarge right by=-\dimexpr1.8cm+\parindent\relax,
    right=\dimexpr1.8cm+\parindent\relax,
    leftrule=1pt,
    rightrule=0pt,
    toprule=0pt,
    bottomrule=0pt,
    breakable,
    nobeforeafter,
    enhanced jigsaw,
    overlay={
      \node[anchor=north east,inner ysep=0pt,align=right,text width=1.8cm] 
        at ([yshift=-0.55ex]frame.north west) {\hfill#1};
    },
    before=\vskip2\itemsep\noindent
  }

\begin{document}

\section*{Sample}

\begin{leftrulebox}[Text Title]
\kant[1]
\kant[2]
\kant[3]
\kant[4]
\kant[5]
\end{leftrulebox}

\end{document}
```

**UPDATE:  MWE 2 for intermitent solution **

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=60pt,top=60pt,right=60pt,bottom=60pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\setitemize{nolistsep,labelsep=1ex,leftmargin=*}

%% colors---
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.8}

%%items--
\newlist{items}{description}{1}
\setlist[items]{align=right,font=\normalfont, leftmargin=1.8in,style=nextline,labelsep=1em,}

%% leftrulebox---
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}
\newtcolorbox{leftrulebox}[1][]{
    colback=white,
    boxrule=10pt
    left=0.5ex,
    top=0pt,
    arc=0pt,
    outer arc=0pt,
    enlarge left by=1.8cm,
    enlarge right by=-\dimexpr1.8cm+\parindent\relax,
    right=\dimexpr1.8cm+\parindent\relax,
    leftrule=1pt,
    rightrule=0pt,
    toprule=0pt,
    bottomrule=0pt,
    breakable,
    nobeforeafter,
    enhanced jigsaw,
    %overlay={
    %   \node[anchor=north east,inner ysep=0pt,align=right,text width=2.6cm] 
    %   at ([yshift=0.5ex]frame.north west) {\hfill#1};%-0.55 hold yshift
    %},
    extras first={
        overlay={%
            \node[anchor=north east,inner ysep=0pt,align=right,text width=2.6cm] 
            at ([yshift=-0.5ex]frame.north west) {\hfill#1};
        },
    },
    extras middle and last={%
        overlay={%
            \node[anchor=north east,inner ysep=0pt,align=right,text width=2.6cm] 
            at ([yshift=-0.5ex]frame.north west) {\hfill};
        },
    },
    %before=\vskip2\itemsep\noindent
    before=\vskip\itemsep\noindent
  }

\begin{document}

\section*{Sample}

\begin{leftrulebox}[Text Title 1]
\kant[1]
\end{leftrulebox}

\begin{leftrulebox}[Text Title 2]
    \kant[2]
\kant[3]
\kant[4]
\kant[5]
\end{leftrulebox}

\begin{leftrulebox}[Text Title 3]
    \kant[3]
    \kant[4]
    \kant[5]
\end{leftrulebox}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imho you are looking for the `overlay unbroken and first` key:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=60pt,top=60pt,right=60pt,bottom=60pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\setitemize{nolistsep,labelsep=1ex,leftmargin=*}

%% colors---
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.8}

%%items--
\newlist{items}{description}{1}
\setlist[items]{align=right,font=\normalfont, leftmargin=1.8in,style=nextline,labelsep=1em,}

%% leftrulebox---
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}
\newtcolorbox{leftrulebox}[1][]{
    colback=white,
    boxrule=10pt
    left=0.5ex,
    top=0pt,
    arc=0pt,
    outer arc=0pt,
    enlarge left by=1.8cm,
    enlarge right by=-\dimexpr1.8cm+\parindent\relax,
    right=\dimexpr1.8cm+\parindent\relax,
    leftrule=1pt,
    rightrule=0pt,
    toprule=0pt,
    bottomrule=0pt,
    breakable,
    nobeforeafter,
    enhanced jigsaw,
    overlay unbroken and first={
       \node[anchor=north east,inner ysep=0pt,align=right,text width=2.6cm]
       at ([yshift=0.5ex]frame.north west) {\hfill#1};%-0.55 hold yshift
    },
    %before=\vskip2\itemsep\noindent
    before=\vskip\itemsep\noindent
  }

\begin{document}

\section*{Sample}

\begin{leftrulebox}[Text Title 1]
\kant[1]
\end{leftrulebox}

\begin{leftrulebox}[Text Title 2]
    \kant[2]
\kant[3]
\kant[4]
\kant[5]
\end{leftrulebox}

\begin{leftrulebox}[Text Title 3]
    \kant[3]
    \kant[4]
    \kant[5]
\end{leftrulebox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a tonne!  I looked up `overlay unbroken and first` in the manual, I never would have found that.

Answer (score 1):

One can try the `extras first` and `extras middle and last` options to provide the specific overlay (with the text) for the first box (the first broken one) and leave the overlay without `#1` for the middle and last boxes in the break sequence.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=60pt,top=60pt,right=60pt,bottom=60pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\setitemize{nolistsep,labelsep=1ex,leftmargin=*}

%% colors---
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.8}

%%items--
\newlist{items}{description}{1}
\setlist[items]{align=right,font=\normalfont, leftmargin=1.8in,style=nextline,labelsep=1em,}

%% leftrulebox---
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}
\newtcolorbox{leftrulebox}[1][]{
    colback=white,
    boxrule=10pt
    left=0.5ex,
    top=0pt,
    arc=0pt,
    outer arc=0pt,
    enlarge left by=1.8cm,
    enlarge right by=-\dimexpr1.8cm+\parindent\relax,
    right=\dimexpr1.8cm+\parindent\relax,
    leftrule=1pt,
    rightrule=0pt,
    toprule=0pt,
    bottomrule=0pt,
    breakable,
    nobeforeafter,
    enhanced jigsaw,
    extras first={
    overlay={%
      \node[anchor=north east,inner ysep=0pt,align=right,text width=1.8cm] 
        at ([yshift=-0.55ex]frame.north west) {\hfill#1};
    },
    },
    extras middle and last={%
      overlay={%
        \node[anchor=north east,inner ysep=0pt,align=right,text width=1.8cm] 
        at ([yshift=-0.55ex]frame.north west) {\hfill};
      },
    },
    before=\vskip2\itemsep\noindent
  }

\begin{document}

\section*{Sample}

\begin{leftrulebox}[Text Title]
\kant[1]
\kant[2]
\kant[3]
\kant[4]
\kant[5]
\end{leftrulebox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Pure genius!  Thanks! It actually breaks multiple `leftrulebox`'s on the same page, but I haven't a clue why (as it's so far random which one shows up with left text and which ones are blank) so I am investigating further.

Comment: @EngBIRD: You're welcome, as always!

Comment: I provided too simple a MWE, I have added a second one if I could possibly ask for your insights with regards to it as well.  Thanks!